# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - apt-get update can't find sources

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, apt

**Update**:

Running `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*` temporarily allows `sudo apt-get update` to work.

**Original**:

I've seen answers to similar questions like this one, but the answers have been 'your version of ubuntu is no longer supported'.

We are using 12.04 Server which is an LTS release. As far as I know, that means precise packages should exist until support is over.

The errors only started showing up about a week or two ago. If it helps, the servers are on Amazon EC2.

I run `sudo apt-get update` and get the following errors:

```
Hit http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu Release.gpg
Hit http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu Release                                                                                                                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                                                                                          
Hit http://packages.treasure-data.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                  
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                            
Hit http://packages.treasure-data.com precise Release                                                                                        
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                                                                                      
Hit http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu/main amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://packages.treasure-data.com precise/contrib amd64 Packages                                                                          
Hit http://packages.treasure-data.com precise/contrib i386 Packages                                                                           
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                                   
Ign http://packages.treasure-data.com precise/contrib TranslationIndex                                                                        
Hit http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                                                                           
Ign http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu/main TranslationIndex                                                                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                                                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources                                                                    
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Ign http://packages.treasure-data.com precise/contrib Translation-en_US                                                                                  
Ign http://packages.treasure-data.com precise/contrib Translation-en                                                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages                                         
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                    
Ign http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu/main Translation-en_US                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                
Ign http://repos.sensuapp.org sensu/main Translation-en                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                         
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                        
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                        
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                   
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages             
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex          
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: check your DNS entry and/or server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this, which might be what you experience, [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=508332).

It seems switching the mirror you use to use

```
us-east-1d.clouds
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/382452/259828) all you need to do is remove `us-east-1.ec2` from the URL.

```
sudo sed -i 's/us-east-1\.ec2\.//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```